# Cross Domain HTTP POST — Single Sign On

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, cross-domain, http-post

I've been trying to find out a solution to my problem for a couple of days.

Searching out gave me many options, none of them I could adapt to my scenario.

I have a web application (C# ASP.NET) which have to post some data to another application, in another domain, working as a SSO. (HTTP POST to another domain with SSL with redirection)

The application on the other domain is expecting a post with some data in plain text on JSON format, to then redirect the user to another page.

I can't use form submit, because it send the form itself to the application, not only my data, so it can't read the data I'm sending.

XMLHttpRequest did work, but then, as an ajax call, it doesn't redirect the user, and I can't get back the Location header from the response.

I don't have control over the other application, and I'm allowed to use only our libraries, so JQuery is not an option.

Does anyone knows how can I achieve this? Server side or client side.

Comment: I would do that on the server side using the WebRequest class.

Comment: I've tried that, but how can I configure the redirection? Without writing the content on my Response?

Comment: Also, where can I define the data I'm passing on the WebRequest ?

Comment: Take a look at the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: I can post the data like that, but after posting, the response should redirect to another page, since this is a single sign on. I've tried seting AllowAutoRedirect and MaximumAutomaticRedirections, but it doesn't seem to make any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Most POST-based cross-domain SSO scenarios work like this:

- fresh unauthenticated browser goes to service provider
- service provider redirects to SSO url with certain query string (usually containing small request signed by service provider, to identify this service provider to SSO gate)
- browser performs a GET to SSO gateway url
- SSO gateway responds with some interactive logon UI
- browser gets user's name/password input and posts them to SSO gateway
- SSO gateway verifies and responds with an HTML page with a small Javascript in it, containing the authentication response data
- Javascript in its turn instructs browser to POST authentication response data back to the service provider URL

Read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0#HTTP_POST_Binding
You will also greatly benefit from reading through SAML2, OAuth and WS-Federation specs.